# ¿Como cambiar el color del texto de la status bar?

Tags: android, color, status-bar

Lo único que encontré en todo internet es esta línea de código:

```
getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_STATUS_BAR);
```

Esta no solo que no me funciona, sino que además, de hacerlo, no me dejaría elegir el color hexadecimal que yo quiera.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que debes hacer es quitar el toolbar por defecto (esto lo recomienda la documentación de android) ya que el toolbar nativo causa más incompatibilidades.

En el manifest:`android:theme="@style/AppTheme">`

En el style: `<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">`

En tu vista agregar el toolbar individualmente

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"></androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
```

para cambiar el color del status bar, en el style:     #303F9F

Para poder cambiar el texto del status bar, ignora todo lo de arriba y prueba esto:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        getWindow().setStatusBarColor(myColor);
        getWindow().setColorMode();
    } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        getWindow().setStatusBarColor(myColor);
    }
```

en el método setColorMode pasale el parametro.

Comment: Hola. gracias por responder. Eso no es para cambiar solamente el fondo en lugar del texto?